# Transition trigger to not work till another transition is complete

Tags: d3.js

I have 2 circles that move right when clicked. Transition takes 10 sec.
What I want

- Requirement 1: If circle 1 is in transition, clicking circle 2 should not trigger transition
- Requirement 2: If circle 1 is in transition, clicking circle 2 should stop circle 1 at its current position and start transition for circle 2

here is my code

```
let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 1800).attr("height", 1800)

svg.selectAll("circles")
.data([100,200])
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("class","zubi")
.attr("cx",50)
.attr("cy",d=>d)
.attr("r",30)
.on("click",function(){
d3.select(this)
  .transition()
  .duration(10000)
  .attr("transform","translate(800)")
})
```

Comment: Those seem like two competing requirements. How can circle 2 not trigger a transition, but also stop circle 1 and then start its own transition? Can you be a little more clear about what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to block any transitions is to just remove the handler when the transition is started, and put it back when it's done:

```js
let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 600).attr("height", 300);

function myClickFunction(d, i) {
  circles.on("click", null);
  d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .duration(5000)
    .attr("transform", "translate(300)")
    .on("end", () => circles.on("click", myClickFunction));
}

let circles = svg.selectAll("circles")
  .data([100, 200])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "zubi")
  .attr("cx", 50)
  .attr("cy", d => d)
  .attr("r", 30)
  .on("click", myClickFunction)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Other possibilities are to add/remove classes, or to get the active transition using [`d3.active`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/#active).

---

You can use [`d3.selection.interrupt`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#selection_interrupt) to cancel any currently running transitions on a selection. I gave the transition a name so you can more fine-grained control. You can have multiple transitions run side by side if you want - if no name is given all transitions are interrupted.

```js
let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 600).attr("height", 300)

let circles = svg.selectAll("circles")
  .data([100, 200])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "zubi")
  .attr("cx", 50)
  .attr("cy", d => d)
  .attr("r", 30)
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
    // Cancel any running transitions
    circles.interrupt("circle-transform");
    d3.select(this)
      .transition("circle-transform")
      .duration(5000)
      .attr("transform", "translate(300)")
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben. It meets my 2nd requirement. 
In the first requirement, I want all current transition to finish. Till that any transition trigger event like click should not work

Comment: As I said in the comment, your requirements conflict with each other. Be more specific. Also, show us what you tried.

Comment: Both cases /requirements are different. Consider them as separate codes

Comment: Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck

Comment: .on("click",function(){

if(no transition is active)
{
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(5000)
      .attr("transform", "translate(300)")
}
  })

Comment: In the above code, I dont know how to determine if there is no active transition. SO the click button will only work when there is no active transition

Comment: Ingenious. Thanks Ruben

Comment: Hi Ruben, If the duration is long...there is a little problem. Because then you have to wait for that duration for click to start the animation.
Do you have another way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224023/discussion-between-ruben-helsloot-and-zubair).